# Return derived type in derived function

Tags: c#, derived-class, derived-types

I have a search form that executes queries returning lists of objects that are sub-classes of a *Contact* class.

When the lists are used in gridviews, properties that only exist in sub-classes (such as *HireDate*) are not displayed because the list contains objects of the base class (*Contact*).

Is there a way to make *GetContacts* in the sub-class return a list of *Employee* instead of a list of *Contact* ? Or a way to "cast" the list of *Contact* into a list of *Employee* ?

Thanks in advance !

```
public abstract class Contact  
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}

public class Employee : Contact  
{
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ContactManager  
{  
     public abstract List<Contact> GetContacts(string searchValue);  
}  

public class EmployeeManager : ContactManager  
{  
     public abstract List<Contact> GetContacts(string searchValue);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, generics can help here:

```
public abstract class ContactManager<T> where T : Contact
{  
  public abstract List<T> GetContacts(string searchValue);  
}

public class EmployeeManager : ContactManager<Employee>
{  
  public abstract List<Employee> GetContacts(string searchValue);  
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [LINQ OfType method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) to get all contacts of a desired type from your collection:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = contactManager.GetContacts("someSearchValue").OfType<Employee>();
```

Comment: I changed my classes to use generics but I get an error saying "_ContactManager<T>_ requires 1 type arguments" (it is passed as a parameter in my search form). Do I have to change classes using _ContactManager_ into generic classes as well ?

Comment: @Anne-Christine Yes, the generic type now forms part of your `ContactManager` type, anywhere that you previously had an instance of `ContactManager`, you'll now need to know which type of contact that they manage to declare the type as `ContactManager<ContactType>`.

Comment: I know a function can be generic without the class being necessary generic but here I pass the generic parameter in a constructor. What should I do ? Thanks !

Comment: @Anne-Christine A quick couple of questions: Are there any other methods on your ContactManager class? Which version of C# are you using?

Comment: `ContactManager` is also a property of my abstract class `Contact` so I can't specify the type in this base class. I only return the specific `ContactManager<ContactType>` in derived classes. Maybe is my approach not a good one ...

Comment: `ContactManager` contains the methods used to communicate with the database (each sub-type refers to a different table). That is methods as `GetContacts`, `GetContact`, `UpdateContact`...  I have .Net 4

Comment: @Anne-Christine Your current design doesn't seem to lend itself too well to generics. I've added an alternate which should be simpler and will enable you to continue with minimal code changes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7002/discussion-between-anne-christine-and-rich-okelly)

Answer (score 1):

You could use generics, something like this:

```
public abstract class ContactManager<TContactType> 
    where TContactType : Contact 
{
    public abstract List<TContactType> GetContacts(string searchValue);  
}

public abstract class EmployeeManager : ContactManager<Employee> 
{
    ...
}
```

This allows you to constrain `ContactManager` to work with specific a specific base type (i.e `Contact`) and further use the specific type (of `Contact`) to drill down with strong typing, for instance, with `Employee`.